# How can I change Keychain permissions without being physically present?

Tags: macos, keychain, server.app

According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Architecture/Architecture.html), for certain operations, the user must be physically present.  However, I am trying to administer a Xcode Server build box via Screen Sharing, and I can't add or remove keychain items because of this restriction. This server is inside of our corporate firewall. Is there a way to remove this restriction for this server?

In the Console, SecurityAgent gives this message when I try to Allow access to a keychain item:

> Ignoring user action since the dialog has received events from an untrusted source

Comment: No, as I said, the server is behind a corporate firewall

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212622/keychain-wont-let-copy-passwords-after-10-11-1-update#comment257296_213099

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh & admin access to the server you could use the security command line tool to manipulate keychain items. It can add & delete passwords, identities and certificates, look at the security man page for the details.

I haven't tried but it looks like `sudo security dump-keychain -i <keychain>` may do what you want.

I suppose that you could use the security tool from the terminal via Screen Sharing if you didn't have ssh access.